# Factorising numbers with a lowest common factor above a certain amount in python

Tags: python, algebra

I'm in the process of creating a calculator for algebra using python - it can currently expand any number of brackets and collect like terms. This time, I'm working on factorising single brackets. The below code (where final is a 2d array containing [[number,character],[number,character], and so on) gathers the common letters and separates them as the second item of 'outbr'.

```
for array in range(len(final)):
  tempnum = final[array][0]
  tempchar = final[array][1]
  for char in tempchar:
    present = True
    for a in range(len(final)):
      if tempchar not in final[a][1]:
        present = False
    if present:
      for a in range(len(final)):
        final[a][1] = list(final[a][1])
        final[a][1].remove(char)
        final[a][1] = "".join(final[a][1])
      outbr[1].append(char)
outbr[1] = "".join(outbr[1])
```

The issue I'm having is that I have a numbers list which contains 0-9, and in theory I could just attempt to divide by every number in this list until it wouldn't divide by any of them. In practice, however, there are several numbers which do not divide by any of these, such as the number 169, with factors of only 1, 169, and 13. Is there any comprehensive way to get around this?

Comment: I don't understand yet what limits you to 0-9 and doesn't allow 13.

Comment: Look at the largest number factor you have and look for factors up to the sqrt of that number.

Comment: mkrieger1 - nothing limits me from using 13, but in principle whichever limit I set, there will always be numbers with higher lowest factors.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. What's an example of `final`, and what results do you expect and get with this code?

Comment: @HugoThompson Allow yourself to work with coefficients that are in ℚ instead of searching for common factors and all your problems disappear.

Comment: @chepner an example of final is -2xy + 2xy, and the desired outcome would be outbr = [2,xy] and final = [[-1,''],[1,'']]

Comment: @Guimoute Almost definitely, but I'm not good enough at programming or maths to do that